# Convert npm packages to plain JS source tree

Tags: javascript, npm, build

Is there any canonical way to create a plain, non-minified JS source tree (eg. using ES modules), that just runs on the desired target (nodejs / browser) from NPM packages?

I like do work in a small non-IDE environment, and never use packaging by myself for small projects. But third-party code is almost always shipped JS and TypeScript inside npm packages that use sophisticated build environments (just got npm, tsc, yarn, parcel, rollup, ... needed to build a single 3rd-party module).

So I would like to have all those build tools "do less" and just emit plain, human-readable JS with somewhat sane file structure (eg. like single file or original source tree). Basically convert a bunch of referencing npm packages to a sane source code tree that doesn't need megabytes of tooling to build itself anymore.

Any ideas welcome!